# javascript regexp replace not working, but string replace works

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I'm working with jQuery and am trying to write a pattern replace, but it doesn't work. I have this:

```
var $featured_rewrite = $('#featured').not('.slideshow');
$featured_rewrite.children().attr('href', $featured_rewrite.find('img').attr('src').replace('/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\./i', '.'));
```

I don't understand why something like this works:

```
.replace('-500x277.', '.')
```

but not this, which I even checked with a tool and made sure it was valid and works:

```
.replace('/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\./i', '.')
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`'/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\./i'` is a string.

`/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\./i` is regex.

```
"hi".match('/hi/')  // returns null
"hi".match(/hi/)    // returns ["hi"]
```

**Edit:** Also, just to be clear, there's nothing wrong with your regex other than the quotes. You may want to consider using `/g` (i.e. `/gi` at the end) if you need to replace more than one match, but that's it.

Comment: Uhh, wasted hour on trials and rereading manuals, never noticed the absence of '' until I came here.

Comment: lolz, took me over 30 mins tryging to figure out why the hell my '/regex/' is not working......

Comment: That's why we love javascript :D Almost every other language consumes "regex as strings" ;)