# Why does my regex fail when trying to indicate beginning of string in replace()?

Tags: node.js, regex

Moving from Perl to Node I'm confused why given the passed object `data` of:

```js
{
  xAxis: 'string',
  yAxis: 'string',
  zAxis: 'string',
  data: '\n' +
    'p.foo {\n' +
    '\tcolor:#000000;\n' +
    '\tfont-family:"Open Sans";\n' +
    '\tfont-size:1em;\n' +
    '\tfont-style:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-variant:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-weight:normal;\n' +
    '\tline-height:1;\n' +
    '\tmargin-bottom:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-left:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-right:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-top:0;\n' +
    '\torphans:1;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-after:auto;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-before:auto;\n' +
    '\ttext-align:left;\n' +
    '\ttext-decoration:none;\n' +
    '\ttext-indent:0;\n' +
    '\ttext-transform:none;\n' +
    '\twidows:1;\n' +
    '}\n' +
    'p.bar {\n' +
    '\tcolor:#000000;\n' +
    '\tfont-family:"Open Sans";\n' +
    '\tfont-size:1em;\n' +
    '\tfont-style:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-variant:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-weight:normal;\n' +
    '\tline-height:1;\n' +
    '\tmargin-bottom:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-left:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-right:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-top:0;\n' +
    '\torphans:1;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-after:auto;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-before:auto;\n' +
    '\ttext-align:left;\n' +
    '\ttext-decoration:none;\n' +
    '\ttext-indent:0;\n' +
    '\ttext-transform:none;\n' +
    '\twidows:1;\n' +
    '}\n'
}
```

if trying to replace any instance of a `p` or `span` from a beginning of line (`^`):

```js
obj.data = obj.data.replace(/^(p|span)(?=\.)/gi, '')
```

the replace will not work and will only work as:

```js
obj.data = obj.data.replace(/(p|span)(?=\.)/gi, '')
```

example:

```js
const test = {
  xAxis: 'string',
  yAxis: 'string',
  zAxis: 'string',
  data: '\n' +
    'p.foo {\n' +
    '\tcolor:#000000;\n' +
    '\tfont-family:"Open Sans";\n' +
    '\tfont-size:1em;\n' +
    '\tfont-style:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-variant:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-weight:normal;\n' +
    '\tline-height:1;\n' +
    '\tmargin-bottom:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-left:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-right:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-top:0;\n' +
    '\torphans:1;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-after:auto;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-before:auto;\n' +
    '\ttext-align:left;\n' +
    '\ttext-decoration:none;\n' +
    '\ttext-indent:0;\n' +
    '\ttext-transform:none;\n' +
    '\twidows:1;\n' +
    '}\n' +
    'p.bar {\n' +
    '\tcolor:#000000;\n' +
    '\tfont-family:"Open Sans";\n' +
    '\tfont-size:1em;\n' +
    '\tfont-style:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-variant:normal;\n' +
    '\tfont-weight:normal;\n' +
    '\tline-height:1;\n' +
    '\tmargin-bottom:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-left:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-right:0;\n' +
    '\tmargin-top:0;\n' +
    '\torphans:1;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-after:auto;\n' +
    '\tpage-break-before:auto;\n' +
    '\ttext-align:left;\n' +
    '\ttext-decoration:none;\n' +
    '\ttext-indent:0;\n' +
    '\ttext-transform:none;\n' +
    '\twidows:1;\n' +
    '}\n'
}

console.log(test.data.replace(/^(p|span)(?=\.)/gi, '')) // doesn't work
console.log(test.data.replace(/(p|span)(?=\.)/gi, '')) // works
```

testing with [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) it works only on the first found:

```js
obj.data = obj.data.replace(new RegExp(/^(p|span)(?=\.)/, 'ig'), '')
```

and seems to be due to the `m` flag needed, so this works:

```js
obj.data = obj.data.replace(new RegExp(/^(p|span)(?=\.)/, 'igm'), '')
```

When reading the type of `obj.data`:

```js
console.log(typeof obj.data) // returns string
```

it shows `string`. Upon research I'm not seeing a reason why but I've read:

- [Javascript replace with regex not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800718/javascript-replace-with-regex-not-working-correctly)
- [javascript regexp replace not working, but string replace works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646703/javascript-regexp-replace-not-working-but-string-replace-works)

Why am I seeing mixed results from my regex in a `replace()` while trying to use `^` when passing in the object's data and why does it only work with RegExp?

---

### Edit:

I think my issue is from a misunderstanding of the [JavaScript flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags). I assumed that because the object's data was a string the flag `g` **Global Search** flag would work but it seems that I need `m` **Multi-line Search** flag.

Comment: `/(p|span)(?=\.)/gim`, you missed the `/m` flag.